# Select text object by name and change font via script

Tags: text-object

I'm needing to know how to access and change the font for a pre-existing text object.  Everything that I have seen uses a new text object.  I've tried looking at the bpy.ops.fonts structure, but can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a Python question?  If so please tag Python on your question and show some Python sample in a screen capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example below is based on windows file location.

```
import bpy

my_name = 'ALGER.TTF'  #name of text object
new_font = 'G:\\Blender Working folders\\Fonts\\ALGER.TTF'  #file location of new font
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if ob.name == my_name:
        ob.data.font = bpy.data.fonts.load(new_font)
```

Comment: Thanks, this bit of code is enough to allow me to figure out what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In edit mode before you start typing select from the Font Panel

- Bold
- Italic

This determines the font choice